# JMeter - ElasticSearch backend listener plugin doesn't work

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have JMeter 3.3 and I added [ElasticSearch backend listener](https://github.com/delirius325/JMeter_ElasticsearchBackendListener) plugin.

I opened JMeter GUI and tried create back end listener and it failed with error:

```
2017-10-17 14:35:24,785 ERROR o.a.j.g.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui for org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/MediaType
    at net.kvak.jmeter.backendlistener.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchBackend.<clinit>(ElasticsearchBackend.java:50) ~[elasticsearch-backend-listener-1.5.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.actionPerformed(BackendListenerGui.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.clearGui(BackendListenerGui.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:348) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AddToTree.doAction(AddToTree.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.MediaType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    ... 26 more
2017-10-17 14:35:30,212 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.AddToTree: Exception while adding a component to tree.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/MediaType
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:359) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AddToTree.doAction(AddToTree.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/MediaType
    at net.kvak.jmeter.backendlistener.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchBackend.<clinit>(ElasticsearchBackend.java:50) ~[elasticsearch-backend-listener-1.5.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.actionPerformed(BackendListenerGui.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.clearGui(BackendListenerGui.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:348) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.MediaType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at net.kvak.jmeter.backendlistener.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchBackend.<clinit>(ElasticsearchBackend.java:50) ~[elasticsearch-backend-listener-1.5.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.actionPerformed(BackendListenerGui.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.clearGui(BackendListenerGui.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:348) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    ... 17 more
```

Sent question in [plugin group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) but didn't receive any answer.

Is it working only with additional plugin/jars? on different version?

Also why doesn't it have page in https://jmeter-plugins.org/ (although it displayed in search results in site)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, realized what was causing the issue when installing the plugin through the plugins manager. Basically, was missing a key/value pair in one of their JSON files for the dependencies.

Made the pull request. For now, to fix the issue all you will need to do is download some JAR files and put them into your "$JMETER_HOME/lib" folder.

[Okio 1.13.0](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/squareup/okio/okio/1.13.0/okio-1.13.0.jar)

[OkHttp 3.9.1](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.9.1/okhttp-3.9.1.jar)

[GSON 2.8.2](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/gson-2.8.2.jar)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a missing dependency or a wrong version of it.

Missing dependency would be okhttp or one of its dependencies.

Add them to jmeter/lib folder.

Comment: Plugin should work with existing jars on JMeter(3.3) or add relevant jar on installation or on release notes, no?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the person who reworked the plugin and put it on jmeter-plugins. It seems to be a conflict between two versions of OkHttpClient. One loaded by the plugin, and the other has yet to be found. Currently investiguating and will release 2.0 as soon as it is fixed.

I want to apologize for the delay on an answer (literally just found your post). For any more help, please oh please, feel free to open an issue on the GitHub repository page :).

https://github.com/delirius325/JMeter_ElasticsearchBackendListener/

Have a good one,

Comment: open issue https://github.com/korteke/JMeter_ElasticsearchBackendListener/issues/2